# How to update time interval in fused location service depending on application being in foreground/background?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

How to have two different location update interval in Fused location when app is in foreground (For example: 5 sec) and when app is in background (For example 5 minute)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the app in in the foreground.

```
private boolean isAppInForeground()
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

    return (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()
            .equalsIgnoreCase(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
}
```

Then in the manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```